# Error in SQL syntax while connecting to database (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create a java program that connects to MySQL database. But its giving me an error, "You have an error with your SQL syntax", and is referring to this line:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO items_in_hand (Item Name, Price (each), Quantity (available)) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

Here's the block:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) itemTable.getModel();
        if(!txt_item.getText().trim().equals("")){
            try{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO items_in_hand (Item Name, Price (each), Quantity (available)) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setString(1,txt_item.getText());         
                st.setString(2,txt_price.getText());  
                st.setString(3,txt_quantity.getText());
                st.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Saved.");
                //model.addRow(new Object[] {txt_item.getText(),txt_price.getText(),txt_quantity.getText()});
            }catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , ex);
            }

        }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you execute that query directly on your database, using mysql client? What does (each) and (available) mean in that insert statement?

Comment: `Price (each)` is an invalid column name due to the space and parenthesis. You need to quote that, e.g. `"Price (each)"` (if ANSI mode is enabled)

Comment: "Price (each)" and "Quantity (available)" are column names in the table

Comment: Horrible column names but apart from that if you have non-standard column names (like this) you need to quote them. Otherwise it will be interpreted as part of the syntax which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thought there are no restrictions with column names, i had no background with mysql. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the query

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO items_in_hand (Item Name, Price (each), Quantity (available)) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

to like below

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO items_in_hand (Item, Price, Quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

Assuming column `Item, Price and Quantity` are present in the `items_in_hand` table.